# Excluding one list of items from another

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a yml file which looks like this:

```
Level 1:
  Seattle:
    Name: "Rick"
    ID: "95155"
    Time: "2:00 PM"
    Car: "Hyundai"
  Denver:
    Name: "Arnold"
    ID: "82594"
    Time: "2:00 PM"
    Car: "Mitsubishi"
Level 2:
   San Antonio:
    Name: "James"
    ID: "96231"
    Time: "2:00 PM"
    Car: "Honda"
  Minneapolis:
    Name: "Ron"
    ID: "73122"
    Time: "2:00 PM"
    Car: "Dodge
```

I need to read the `ID` values into an array for processing, then remove them from another array. What are good ways to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove them from another array"?

Comment: If I had array2 with (possibly) a superset of the IDs in the YML file, I would want to remove the duplicates from it.

Comment: array2 is the 'another array' referred to in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can read ID values into an array for processing in the below way :

```
require 'yaml'

yml = <<-_end_

---

Level1:
 Seattle:
  Name: "Rick"
  ID: "95155"
  Time: "2:00 PM"
  Car: "Hyundai"
 Denver:
  Name: "Arnold"
  ID: "82594"
  Time: "2:00 PM"
  Car: "Mitsubishi"
Level 2:
 San Antonio:
  Name: "James"
  ID: "96231"
  Time: "2:00 PM"
  Car: "Honda"
 Minneapolis:
  Name: "Ron"
  ID: "73122"
  Time: "2:00 PM"
  Car: "Dodge"

_end_

hsh = YAML.load(yml)
# => {"Level1"=>
#      {"Seattle"=>
#        {"Name"=>"Rick", "ID"=>"95155", "Time"=>"2:00 PM", "Car"=>"Hyundai"},
#       "Denver"=>
#        {"Name"=>"Arnold",
#         "ID"=>"82594",
#         "Time"=>"2:00 PM",
#         "Car"=>"Mitsubishi"}},
#     "Level 2"=>
#      {"San Antonio"=>
#        {"Name"=>"James", "ID"=>"96231", "Time"=>"2:00 PM", "Car"=>"Honda"},
#       "Minneapolis"=>
#        {"Name"=>"Ron", "ID"=>"73122", "Time"=>"2:00 PM", "Car"=>"Dodge"}}}

def hash_value(hsh)
  keys = hsh.keys
  keys.each_with_object([]){|e,ar| hsh[e].is_a?(Hash) ? ar << hash_value(hsh[e]).flatten.uniq : ar << hsh["ID"]}.flatten
end

hash_value(hsh) # => ["95155", "82594", "96231", "73122"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the YAML, if it is contained in a file, then:

```
levels = YAML.load_file(path)
```

if it is contained in a string, then:

```
levels = YAML.load(path)
```

Once parsed, to get the ids into an array:

```
ids = levels.values.flat_map(&:values).map do |city|
  city['ID']
end
```

with this result:

```
p ids # => ["95155", "82594", "96231", "73122"]
```

To remove these ids from another array of ids:

```
another_array_of_ids = ["123456", "82594", "96231"]
another_array_of_ids -= ids
p another_array_of_ids # => ["123456"]
```